# Python print in terminal returning 'invalid syntax'

Tags: python, unix

Im using the terminal on my mac to run some python and when i try to print a string i get an invalid syntax error.

```
Michaels-MBP:~ mike$ python text.py
File "text.py", line 2
print(‘hi’)
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I've tried it with single quotes and with and without parentheses but i keep getting that error, what is wrong.

Comment: In python, strings should be written either inside single quotes(`'`) or in double quotes(`"`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should be:

```
print('hi')
```

You have proper British quotes `‘foo’`. Those are the right symbols to use when writing human-readable texts, but Python wants actual single quotes `'`.

Your editor probably has some kind of smart-quotes feature enabled, it is wise to turn this off when writing code (e.g. configure your editor to detect extensions like `.py`).

Comment: If you look closely, you should see that the opening and closing single quotes are different, suggesting that @PM2Ring is correct

Comment: Yes that’s right, those are British quotes, apostrophe was just the first thing that came to my mind.